# Reading from the terminal inside a callback

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My program `process.stdout.write();` in the terminal every time a socket is received from the client to the server. However, I'm not able to pass to my code a callback to read from the terminal (`process.stderr.on`) the data stream and send it back as a new socket (from the server) to the client.

For now, this is my code - that does not work after the `.write`:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('SEND_COORDINATES', (data) => {
      const dataToString = `${data.x.toString()}, ${data.y.toString()}`;
      process.stdout.write(dataToString);
    }, (data) => {
      process.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        socket.emit("SEND_AGAIN_COORDINATES", {data};
      });
    }
    )
});
```

I'm not sure I can do that so there's maybe something with the logic that I don't get. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: First, any reason you're writing to `stdout` and listening for data on `stderr`?
Second, you should open your listener before writing data to stdout. In fact, you should open your listener even outside of the "connection" event, otherwise you're opening one listener for each socket connection and that sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a third parameter to the .on method. Looks like you are using socket.io. If that is the case take a look at the documentation on their site for the .on:

https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-on-eventName-callback

Usually this is the case, but a .on is inherited from the Node EventEmitter. Let's go there now.

https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener

> ### emitter.on(eventName, listener)
>
> - eventName < string > | < symbol >  The name of the event.
> - listener < Function > The callback function
> - Returns: < EventEmitter >

There are only 2 arguments for the emitter.on so your 2nd callback or 3rd parameter is not seen.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('SEND_COORDINATES', (data) => {}, (data) => {
        process.stderr.on('data', (data) => {});
    })
});
```

Deleted some of the innards so you can see it a little better. Everything needs to go into the FIRST callback for socket.on event.